# Spark reparition() function increases number of tasks per executor, how to increase number of executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on IBM Server of 30gb ram (12 cores engine), I have provided all the cores to spark but still, it uses only 1 core, I tried while loading the file and got successful with the command

```
val name_db_rdd = sc.textFile("input_file.csv",12)
```

and able to provide all the 12 cores to the processing for the starting jobs but I want to split the operation in between the intermediate operations to the executors, so that it can use all the 12 cores.

Image - description

```
val new_rdd = rdd.repartition(12)
```

[image]

As you can see in this image only 1 executor is running and repartition function split the data to many tasks at one executor.

Comment: Please include your SparkConf configuration and details of how you are launching your application, the above is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you're launching the job, but you probably want to add --num-executors to your command line when you're launching your spark job.

Something like

```
spark-submit
    --num-executors 10 \
    --driver-memory 2g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
```

might work well for you.

Have a look on the [Running Spark on Yarn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) for more details, though some of the switches they mention are Yarn specific.

Comment: Take into account that in case the file is relatively small, *Spark* could still be creating a single split/partition even having declared to use 10 executors. Specifying the partition number in the program might also be necessary. Another way is to change the block size and leave *Spark* do the splitting, though this approach is somehow a little more messy...

Comment: I've already provided these details in my spark application, above conditions I've provided is after these steps taken.